# Magento - OnePage Checkout - Hide Payment method depending on Shipping Method

Tags: php, magento, payment, onepage-checkout

I have asked this question on [Magento Stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41075/onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method) without any success, hence me now asking here.

---

I'm using Magento Community Edition 1.9.0.1 and have correctly created and registered my module, but I can't seem to detect the shipping methods. Basically, I want to hide **Cash on Delivery** if *Flat Rate* or *Free Shipping* is chosen. Here is the code I have for my observer class:

```js
class Kol_PaymentToggle_Model_Observer
{
  public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
      $event  = $observer->getEvent();
      $method = $event->getMethodInstance();
      $result = $event->getResult(); 
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
      if($shippingMethod == "standardshipping" || $shippingMethod == "free") {
        if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ) {
              $result->isAvailable = false;
          }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm guessing that I haven't used the correct shipping method code names or payment method code names, but I'm unsure. Anyone has any advice?

I only have 3 shipping methods enabled:

- **Collect In Store** 
  Title = Collect in Store 
  Method Name = Collect In Store ([Extension link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/collect-in-store-checkout-shipping-option.html))
- **Flat Rate** 
  Title = Standard Delivery 
  Method Name = Standard Shipping
- **Free Shipping** 
  Title = Free Delivery 
  Method Name = Free

Output of *config.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kol_PaymentToggle>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Kol_PaymentToggle>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Kol_PaymentToggle_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: can you please tell me  on which event the code is fire?

Comment: Hi Amit. It is meant to fire on the onepage checkout at the point where the person must choose a payment method.

Comment: Sorry, you meant the event in code, correct? In the config.xml for this module the event is called `payment_method_is_active`, and the observer is called `paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active`

Comment: @Amit: Edited my post to include `config.xml` output

Comment: can you tell are going to  paymentMethodIsActive function on  payment_method_is_active event?

Comment: I know that the function does fire. If I change the condition on line 9 to `if($shippingMethod != "blahblahblah") {...`, then indeed the cash on delivery payment option does not show

Comment: it should be freeshipping_freeshipping and standardshipping_standardshipping

Comment: Aah, I see! That's what I was looking for actually - the actual method code names. Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Amit. Sorry, I tried this, but it unfortunately does not work. I have also noticed that I now get this error on the Product Detail page: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getShippingAddress() on a non-object in /var/www/app/code/local/Kol/PaymentToggle/Model/Observer.php on line 10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63785/discussion-between-magz-and-amit-bera).

Comment: Ok, no worries...when you have some free time I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As for I got, you trying to hide some payment methods based on shipping method. For this you don't need to observe things at all. Simply you can do this, just follow me,

Every methods(in one page check out) post the methods which are chosen to the next level. so you can get the shipping method which are chosen, in payment method level. Just print the post things in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

in this add below one,

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

So now you can get the shipping methods which are chosen previous step. And note it, so now, you can add just simple logic (if else) condition in same file for hiding payment,

For example here I want hide `check / money order` payment method, if shipping method is `flat`. Here the payment method code is `checkmo`. you can get payment method code by simply printing that variable like `echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();` in same file. so here just add simple if else ,

```
  <?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();


    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
       echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();


if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
?>
```

Here,

```
 if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
```

checks the shipping method and skip the payment method which we don't want to display. That's it. Please comment here if you have any doubt.

**Note:**

```
 shipping_method => flatrate_flatrate
 paymet_method   => checkmo
```

Comment: @Elvarasan: Thank you! I knew I should be modifying the PHTML instead. makes a lot more sense. I'll override the PHTML for my sub-theme

Comment: Question: where would I stick `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`

Comment: Elvarasan, you are a star! Works beautifully. Even if I go back a few steps and select a different shipping method, it updates..no need to check for Mage checkout session or anything like that

Comment: If i have OnePage Checkout from IWD, i have all steps in same page, so i can't use POST. How can i have in this methods.phtml the array $_shippingRateGroups from shipping_method/available.phtml?
If i can obtain this, I can do a check like this
`...
foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
  if ( array_key_exists('freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroupsCheck )) {
   if($_code == 'msp_cashondelivery') {
       continue;       
   }
     }
...`

Answer (score 1):

Though [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26608886/2869218) works, it is not an elegant solution since it prompts us to check the post data in a phtml file which is not a good method. Instead, you should definitely look for an event to do this job.

Luckily we have a perfect event to do this job and which is `payment_method_is_active`. Please see [the detailed answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197231/3535).

Basically, you need to set the payment method inactive through this method as you can see in the answer.

Comment: I totally agree. Making such checks in the template file is not best practice. Also it won't work if the theme is changing

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution for the OnePage Checkout IWD provided by @Simbus82:

```
$shipping = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

foreach ($methods as $_method): 
        $_code = $_method->getCode(); 
        if ( $shipping == 'matrixrate_matrixrate_140' or $shipping == 'matrixrate_matrixrate_148' ) { 
            if($_code != 'cashondelivery') { 
                continue;   
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Really sorry to revive this old post. Where exactly do I place this code? In which file?