# code for table rates shipping method & cash on delivery" payment method in magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am using this shipping "Table rates" and "webshopapp matrix rates" shipping methods.

what i need is that , if  we use table rates shipping method, i want to hide "cash on delivery" payment method.

i am following this link : [Magento - OnePage Checkout - Hide Payment method depending on Shipping Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604267/magento-onepage-checkout-hide-payment-method-depending-on-shipping-method)

please help me to find what is the code for

1)table rates shipping method

2)cash on delivery" payment method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a simple **if** statement in your **available.phtml** file. in

> app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

In this file you can see some codes like

```
 <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
    <?php $codes=$_rate->getCode();?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Below these lines there is code to display the shipping method and the radio button to check the shipping method.You just need to check the condition here.

```
<?php if($codes=='shipping_method_code' ): ?>
```

If the codes matches to your table rate code then you can do what you want.You can check like this as your need.

Hope this will help.

Comment: hi, this is available.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/tRhfGqUr can you tell me in ehich line i have to place this code : <?php if($codes=='shipping_method_code' ): ?>

Comment: Hey, after line 34 you can perform the if condition check. Inspect the shipping method in your checkout page to get more insight and you can visualize the code flow.

Comment: If this helps than don't forget to accept and vote up this will help others too to get the answer to similar problem.

Comment: is i have to use this code ?  = >   <?php endif ? >

Comment: i pasted above line after line number 35  , but after " Shipping information" , it redirecting to "my cart" page.

Comment: hi, i got solution here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62124/what-is-the-code-for-table-rates-shipping-method-cash-on-delivery-payment-met/62125?noredirect=1#comment83284_62125